# Linebreak for both HTML and CLI?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a script which can be called both from browser and CLI. It produces output, so adding a new line is a must. But, if youre viewing from a browser, the .php should use `<br>` while watching from CLI its the `\r\n` or `PHP_EOL`:

```
echo 'output1';
if $browser
{
    echo '<br>';
}
else
{
    echo "\r\n";
}
echo 'output2';
```

Isnt there any universal character?

Comment: There is not. You will need to know how your program is being invoked in order to properly format the output. This seems like a good case for some templating :)

Comment: you could output the `\r\n` and use specific CSS in browser scenario (`white-space:pre`)

Comment: `$eol = php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ? "\n" : '<br>'; echo 'output1'.$eol.'output2';`

Answer (score 1):

Versions of PHP binaries could vary, for example on servers that have `fastcgi` the php binary might point to 
`php-cgi`.

So to test cli in an interface independent manner checking the contents of the `$_SERVER` variable for example is a more preferred way.

I think this would handle all the checks from whether the script is run from

1. Command line
2. As a cron job
3. PHP binary
4. Browser

> ```
> function is_cli() {
>   return ((empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) and ! isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) and count($_SERVER['argv']) > 0) ||defined('STDIN')) ? true : false;
> }
>
> echo 'output1';
> if (is_cli()) {
>   echo "\r\n";
> } else {
>   echo '<br>';
> }
> echo 'output2';
> ```